# what was Samson's wife crying about the first three days

Tags: judges

Judges 14:15 says

> On the fourth day, they said to Samson’s wife, “Coax your husband into explaining the riddle for us, or we will burn you and your father’s household to death. Did you invite us here to steal our property

But Judges 14:17 says

> She cried the whole seven days of the feast.

How could she have been crying the seven days of the feast when they only threatened her on the fourth day, what was she crying about the first three days? Even worse, the footnote for Judges 14:15 says "on the seventh day"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting on Judges 14:17, Benson (and Ellicott) suggest this:

> Jdg 14:17. She wept before him, the seven days — Or rather, the rest
> of the seven days; that is, either after the third day, (Jdg 14:14,)
> or all the seventh day, from the time her countrymen came and
> threatened her till she persuaded Samson to tell her the riddle.

Similarly, Matthew Pool suggest this:

> The seven days, while their feast lasted, i.e. on the residue of the
> seven days, to wit, after the third day. It is a familiar synecdoche.
> Or, on the seventh of the days on which the feast was; and then the
> following clause, on the seventh day, is only the noun repeated for
> the pronoun, on that day; as is most frequent, as 1 Kings 8:1, Solomon
> assembled—unto Solomon, i.e. unto himself.